# Implementing 3 variable boolean function od 2-1 multiplexers

Tags: multiplexer, boolean-algebra, karnaugh-map

Recently i've been given a task from my lecturer to implement  \$f=\sum(1, 3, 4, 5, 7)\$ on "2-bit multiplexers". That's it. I assume he meant 2:1 MUX.

I've came up with following k-map...

+------+---+---+
| AB/C | 0 | 1 |
+------+---+---+
| 00   | 0 | **1** |
| 01   | 0 | **1** |
| 11   | 0 | **1** |
| 10   | **1** | **1** |
+------+---+---+

\$A\overline B + C\$

... and following 2 schematics:

1)

[image]

2)
[image]

Since the execrise's desscription consists plural multiplexers- is the second example OK? And if the description would mention using only one MUX- is the first example OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are ok. You have saved 4 pcs of 2 to 1 muxes when compared to canonical 8 input solution.